# En VB encuentro My.Application.Info.Version la conversión a C# seria?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows

tengo la siguiente linea en vb

```
My.Application.Info.Version.ToString
```

la conversión mas literal a c# como seria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En c# tienes el objeto `Application` podrias ver si obtienes el mismo dato usando

[Application.ProductVersion Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=netframework-4.5)

algo como ser

```
lblVersion.Text = Application.ProductVersion;
```